# ¿Cómo obtengo datos ya registrados en un formulario sin necesidad de colocarlos en uno?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Ok, hace poco pregunte sobre como realizar un sistema de votaciones parecido a hacker news/reddity y he logrado hacerlo de una manera sencilla para que cuenta los votos por medio de un link y que me redirija a la pagina principal mostrando el voto actualizado por supuesto.

Bueno eso funciona más o menos así en este momento, pero tengo el problema de que ahora, cuando le doy al botón lo que hace es llevarme al formulario donde solo tengo los campos `user` y `vote`pero me dice que el campo es requerido y es cierto, pero lo que yo quiero es saltarme ese paso e ir directamente a la redirección.

forms.py

```
class VoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = New
        exclude = ('title', 'url')
```

y mi vista

```
class NewVote(UpdateView):
    model = New
    form_class = VoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        if form.instance.vote:
            form.instance.vote += 1
        form.save()
        return redirect('New:list')
```

cuando hago votar o update, en este caso, me lleva a [este](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCMfx.jpg) formulario y después le puedo dar a un enlace como el hello ikenshu que no lleva a ninguna parte, me aparece [este](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2X6b.jpg) lo que quiero evitarme son esos dos formulario para que sume directamente y me redirija a la pagina principal

como puedo escoger esos dos parametros para que no tengan que mostrarme un formulario?

Gracias de antemano!

EDITO:

urls.py

```
app_name = 'New'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', NewList.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^add/', NewAdd.as_view(), name='add'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewEdit.as_view(), name='edit'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^vote/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VoteView.as_view(), name='vote'),
]
```

Comment: me gustari ver el archivo de urls.py

Comment: listo, ahi lo agregue

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo usted requiere actualizar el campo "vote" de su modelo New, cada ves que alguien de un voto positivo. Como usted dice quiere evitar los formularios y hacerlo en una misma pagina. Podrías usar varias formas de manejar esto, la mejor seria con la ayuda de javascript y enviando una petición ajax y recoger la información por GET, o bien, por medio de un formulario que debes cargar en la vista y validarlo en otra vista y redireccionar de nuevo a la pagina.

De igual modo se quiere mayor ayuda formule mejor la pregunta y publique también su modelo.